# lost connection to mysql server during query while i am trying to run a query

Tags: mysql, xampp, connection, heidisql

The error i am receiving is lost connection to mysql server during query, i am not sure why i am receiving this error im getting it while trying to run this code, my connection is fine as ive ran previous queries before this, if anyone can tell me how to resolve this it would help loads, many thanks

````
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Server version:               10.6.4-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL Version:             11.3.0.6295
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

INSERT INTO `player_outfits` (`id`, `citizenid`, `outfitname`, `model`, `skin`, `outfitId`) VALUES
    (1, 'UTS15067', 'swat', '1885233650', '{"blush":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"accessory":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lowering":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"makeup":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"nose_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"face":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":24,"defaultTexture":0},"ageing":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"arms":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":20,"defaultTexture":0},"vest":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":11,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_color":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_4":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"decals":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"moles":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"t-shirt":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":0,"item":40,"defaultTexture":0},"neck_thikness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"shoes":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":0,"item":25,"defaultTexture":0},"hat":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":6,"item":7,"defaultTexture":0},"lipstick":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"eye_opening":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"mask":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"bracelet":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"ear":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"watch":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"bag":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"pants":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":2,"item":46,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_hole":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"torso2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":110,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_back_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"glass":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":6,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrown_high":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_0":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"hair":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"lips_thickness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_5":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"beard":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"eyebrows":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"eyebrown_forward":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0}}', 'outfit-6-2043'),
    (2, 'NIQ00503', 'work', '1885233650', '{"blush":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"accessory":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":1,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_opening":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"makeup":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":35,"defaultTexture":1},"nose_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"face":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"ageing":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"arms":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":4,"item":17,"defaultTexture":0},"vest":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":13,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_color":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_4":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"decals":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"moles":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_hole":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"neck_thikness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"lipstick":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"hat":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"bracelet":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrows":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":30,"defaultTexture":1},"mask":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lowering":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"ear":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"watch":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"bag":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"pants":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":7,"item":9,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"torso2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":31,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_back_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"shoes":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":0,"item":2,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrown_high":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_0":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"hair":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":1,"item":21,"defaultTexture":0},"lips_thickness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_5":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"glass":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"t-shirt":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":0,"item":15,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"beard":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":10,"defaultTexture":1},"cheek_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrown_forward":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0}}', 'outfit-1-4143'),
    (3, 'UTS15067', 'swat biglips', '1885233650', '{"blush":{"defaultTexture":1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultItem":-1},"accessory":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"cheek_3":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"eye_opening":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":-71,"defaultItem":0},"makeup":{"defaultTexture":1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultItem":-1},"nose_1":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"face":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":24,"defaultItem":0},"ageing":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":5,"defaultItem":-1},"arms":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":20,"defaultItem":0},"vest":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":11,"defaultItem":0},"eye_color":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":12,"defaultItem":-1},"nose_4":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"decals":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"moles":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":2,"defaultItem":-1},"eyebrows":{"defaultTexture":1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultItem":-1},"bracelet":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultItem":-1},"chimp_hole":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"neck_thikness":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"hat":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":6,"item":7,"defaultItem":-1},"t-shirt":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":40,"defaultItem":1},"mask":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"cheek_1":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"ear":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultItem":-1},"watch":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultItem":-1},"bag":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"jaw_bone_width":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"pants":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":46,"defaultItem":0},"chimp_bone_width":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"chimp_bone_lowering":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"nose_2":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"torso2":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":110,"defaultItem":0},"jaw_bone_back_lenght":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"cheek_2":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"nose_3":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"eyebrown_high":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"nose_0":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"hair":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":50,"item":58,"defaultItem":0},"lips_thickness":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":-50,"defaultItem":0},"nose_5":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"lipstick":{"defaultTexture":1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultItem":-1},"glass":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":7,"item":18,"defaultItem":0},"chimp_bone_lenght":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0},"beard":{"defaultTexture":1,"texture":1,"item":26,"defaultItem":-1},"shoes":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":25,"defaultItem":1},"eyebrown_forward":{"defaultTexture":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultItem":0}}', 'outfit-4-1183'),
    (4, 'TPO23495', 'pd1', '1885233650', '{"blush":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"accessory":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":1,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lowering":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"makeup":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"nose_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"face":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":43,"defaultTexture":0},"ageing":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"arms":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":33,"defaultTexture":0},"vest":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":11,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_color":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":9,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_4":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"decals":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":31,"defaultTexture":0},"hat":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrows":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"neck_thikness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"glass":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"moles":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"mask":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"ear":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"watch":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"bag":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"pants":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":1,"item":52,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_opening":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":5,"defaultTexture":0},"torso2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":1,"item":102,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_back_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"bracelet":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"t-shirt":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":1,"item":40,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrown_high":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_0":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":5,"defaultTexture":0},"hair":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":52,"defaultTexture":0},"lips_thickness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_5":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"lipstick":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"jaw_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_hole":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"beard":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":18,"defaultTexture":1},"shoes":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":0,"item":61,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrown_forward":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0}}', 'outfit-7-6923'),
    (6, 'XPC15456', 'officer', '-1667301416', '{"blush":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"accessory":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":3,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lowering":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":10,"defaultTexture":0},"makeup":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"nose_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"face":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":21,"defaultTexture":0},"ageing":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"arms":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":3,"defaultTexture":0},"vest":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_color":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":23,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_4":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"decals":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"hat":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_opening":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"bracelet":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"glass":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":13,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":4,"defaultTexture":0},"moles":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"neck_thikness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"mask":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"t-shirt":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":1,"item":67,"defaultTexture":0},"ear":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"watch":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"bag":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"pants":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":2,"item":31,"defaultTexture":0},"lipstick":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":0,"defaultTexture":1},"shoes":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":2,"item":38,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":2,"defaultTexture":0},"torso2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":153,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_back_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":10,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrown_high":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_0":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":5,"defaultTexture":0},"hair":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":21,"item":3,"defaultTexture":0},"lips_thickness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_5":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":5,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_hole":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":6,"defaultTexture":0},"beard":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"eyebrows":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":1,"defaultTexture":1},"eyebrown_forward":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0}}', 'outfit-8-5726'),
    (11, 'YKF02896', 'outfit lspd', '1885233650', '{"blush":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"accessory":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lowering":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"makeup":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"nose_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"face":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":9,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"ageing":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"arms":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":33,"defaultTexture":0},"vest":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":11,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_color":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":3,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_4":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"decals":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":31,"defaultTexture":0},"moles":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"neck_thikness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"lipstick":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"cheek_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"bracelet":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_hole":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":5,"defaultTexture":0},"mask":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":121,"defaultTexture":0},"hat":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":2,"item":58,"defaultTexture":0},"ear":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"watch":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"bag":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":3,"defaultTexture":0},"pants":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":1,"item":52,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_opening":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":14,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":7,"defaultTexture":0},"torso2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":102,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_back_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":2,"defaultTexture":0},"t-shirt":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":1,"item":40,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":5,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrown_high":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_0":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"hair":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":2,"item":19,"defaultTexture":0},"lips_thickness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_5":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"glass":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":2,"item":6,"defaultTexture":0},"shoes":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":0,"item":61,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":4,"defaultTexture":0},"beard":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":10,"defaultTexture":1},"eyebrows":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":3,"item":2,"defaultTexture":1},"eyebrown_forward":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0}}', 'outfit-5-2375'),
    (14, 'WDW87525', 'Ocean1', '-1667301416', '{"blush":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"accessory":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":1,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lowering":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":3,"defaultTexture":0},"makeup":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":4,"item":3,"defaultTexture":1},"nose_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":2,"defaultTexture":0},"face":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":7,"item":21,"defaultTexture":0},"ageing":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"arms":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":14,"defaultTexture":0},"vest":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":20,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_color":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_4":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":3,"defaultTexture":0},"decals":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"hat":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":2,"defaultTexture":0},"neck_thikness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"moles":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"bracelet":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"mask":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":121,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_opening":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":10,"defaultTexture":0},"ear":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"watch":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"bag":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_width":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":5,"defaultTexture":0},"pants":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":1,"item":31,"defaultTexture":0},"shoes":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":0,"item":24,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"torso2":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":99,"defaultTexture":0},"jaw_bone_back_lenght":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"lipstick":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":24,"item":1,"defaultTexture":1},"t-shirt":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":0,"item":3,"defaultTexture":0},"eyebrown_high":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_0":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"hair":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":36,"item":60,"defaultTexture":0},"lips_thickness":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_5":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"glass":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":1,"item":30,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_hole":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":2,"defaultTexture":0},"beard":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"eyebrows":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":3,"item":12,"defaultTexture":1},"eyebrown_forward":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0}}', 'outfit-2-6338'),
    (16, 'ZDJ52636', '1', '1885233650', '{"blush":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"accessory":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":1,"defaultTexture":0},"cheek_3":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"chimp_bone_lowering":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"makeup":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"nose_1":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"face":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":8,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"ageing":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"arms":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"vest":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"eye_color":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"nose_4":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"decals":{"defaultItem":0,"texture":0,"item":0,"defaultTexture":0},"moles":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"lipstick":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":1,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":1},"bracelet":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":0,"item":-1,"defaultTexture":0},"shoes":{"defaultItem":1,"texture":2,"item":42,"defaultTexture":0},"hat":{"defaultItem":-1,"texture":20,"item":104,"defaultTexture":0},"neck_thikness":```
````

Comment: There should be a debug file showing why the problem is caused, if you share that error, it will help us understand why the problem is caused.

Comment: Are You Connection Is local or SSH Connection?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @@global.max_allowed_packet = 1048576*10;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it